# App Crashes When Making a Call in [matrix]'s VoIP with webRTCDelegate

Tags: webrtc, flutter-webrtc, matrix-org

When receiving an incoming call or making an outgoing call, the WebRTCDelegate's handleNewCall function is triggered as expected. However, immediately afterwards, the application unexpectedly crashes, leading to an abrupt closure. This issue disrupts the expected call-handling flow. But this works well in Android mobile.

In Android calling works well, But when we make it in a Linux desktop the app crashes when a call is made.

This is the log message I got before the app crashes.

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(1015)] The 'FlutterWebRTC/peerConnectionEvent2896EFFA-C6B6-4DE5-AFA7-D693FC33E2F3' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel.
See https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#channels-and-platform-threading for more information.
flutter: [Matrix] Negotiation is needed!
flutter: [Matrix] CallEvent: CallEvent.kFeedsChanged
Warning: Failed to respond to a message. This is a memory leak.
Lost connection to device.

Exited.
```